# How do I get characters other than commas and digits in Java?

Tags: java, regex

How do I pull characters other than commas and digits in Java?
* in android studio

Let's say I have:
100 ₽ / 
$4,99 / 
9,99 € / 
100 CA$ / 
9,49 USD

It is necessary that the letters should also be

```
String regex = "\\p{Sc}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a);   ---> doesn't work like i want
```

the code above does not fit, it does not pull out the currency letters, and if it is not a sign, it writes null

How can I get their currency signs out of them (not all at once) (the canadian dollar together with CA), and the other currency USD
I understand, I need to filter as something to select everything except numbers and commas

Please tell me how to do this.

EXAMPLE:
I have a number and I have a currency (currency I get from google play)

```
currency = GET CURRENCY OF VALUE ($ or USD, or CAD$, or AUD$)

I wanna "my number" + currency = "number currency"
"4,99" + "$" = "99 $" or
"99,9" + "USD" = "99 USD" or
"9,99" + "CAD$" = "99 CAD$" or
"99" + "AUD$" = "99 AUD$"
```

Comment: Please describe the expected output in more detail / more clear.

Comment: What is a? please provide a minimum working example :)

Comment: @Polygnome   EXAMPLE:
I have a number and I have a currency what (currency I get from google play)

    I wanna "my number" + currency = "number currency"
    "99" + "$" = "99 $" or
    "99" + "USD" = "99 USD"

Comment: @Lars Nielsen i wrote a example in edit

Comment: @ArtemZaevsky That is not a minumum working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example shows a regexp to extract currency info from the string:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^0-9\\,\\.\\s\\/]+)");
Arrays.asList("100 ₽ / $4,99 / 9,99 € / 100 CA$ / 9,49 USD", "100,00₽", "4,999.90 US$")
      .forEach(s -> {
          Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
          System.out.println(s);
          while (m.find()) {
              System.out.println("\t" + m.group(1));
          }
      });
```

*Output*

```
100 ₽ / $4,99 / 9,99 € / 100 CA$ / 9,49 USD
    ₽
    $
    €
    CA$
    USD
100,00₽
    ₽
4,999.90 US$
    US$
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex Rudenko. It's works like I wanted

Comment: You're welcome!  Btw, your initial approach was quite ok.  The problem is that RUR symbol ₽ is not recognized yet as a currency symbol with your initial regexp `\\p{Sc}`.  As well as some other currencies including manat, lari and bitcoin :)  [This link](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd24t7nr) shows some ignored currencies that are listed as [Unicode currencies](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm).